# Hex find 20 and replace with 00 in LInux

Tags: linux, sed, hex, tr

I have a very large file (21G) and I want to do a find/replace hex (find 20 and replace with 00).  I was using `tr < filename* -d '\000' > newfilename`
Obviously, this is only removing NULL.  Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Are you wondering how to replace, or how to handle the large file?

Comment: Seems like a job for sed rather than tr.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $ sed 's/\x20/\x00/g' file > newfile
```

Or even

```
   $ sed -i 's/\x20/\x00/g' file
```

If you don't want to copy the file and just to replace the values in the source file

Comment: second example will only output the result

Comment: don't, just put -i which stands for in-place changes

Comment: I tried this and it seems to have worked fine:  tr < oldfile* -d '\000''\040' > newfile

Comment: Great, it's always more than one way to do something in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question... you say you want to replace hex 20 with hex 0, yet you use a command to *delete* hex 20 rather than *replace* it?

Anyway, in general, the command to replace character `a` with character `b` in a file is:

```
tr 'a' 'b' < inputFile > outputFile
```

In your case, you want to replace hex 20, but `tr` only likes octal, so you now have two choices... either change the hex 20 to octal 40 for `tr` yourself:

```
tr '\040' '\000' < inputFile > outputFile
```

or, let the shell translate your hex 20 into something that `tr` can understand using:

```
tr $'\x20' '\000' < inputFile > outputFile
```

This last form is called `ANSI C Quoting` and is described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: I was mistaken.  I had it backwards, which is why the previous worked